# I want to show, without taking a limit, that $2^\sqrt{2 \log n} \in Ω(\log^2n)$ and $2^\sqrt{2 \log n} \in O(\sqrt{2}^{\log n})$

Tags: time-complexity, big-o-notation

I want to show, without taking a limit, that $2^\sqrt{2 \log n} \in Ω(\log^2n)$ and $2^\sqrt{2 \log n} \in O(\sqrt{2}^{\log n})$.

I will omit what I have tried as it has not been useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that

$$2^\sqrt{2\log n}=2^{\frac{2\log n}{\sqrt{2\log n}}}$$$$=\left(2^{\log n}\right)^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\log n}}}$$

$$=n^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\log n}}}$$
$$=\sqrt[\sqrt{2\log n}]{n}.$$

Now after taking $\log$ from $=\sqrt[\sqrt{2\log n}]{n}$ and $\log^2n$, you get
$$\log\left(\sqrt[\sqrt{2\log n}]{n}\right)=\Theta\left(\sqrt{\log n}\right).$$
Also  $$\log\left(\log ^2n\right)=\Theta\left(\log\log n\right).$$
Since
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{\log n}}{\log\log n}=\infty$$
So $$2^{\sqrt{2\log n}} \in \Omega(\log^2n).$$

For second problem, note that
$$\sqrt{2}^{\log n}=\sqrt{n}.$$
So $$2^{\sqrt{2\log n}} =\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{2}^{\log n}).$$

Comment: @integrator $$\log\left(\sqrt[\sqrt{2\log n}]{n}\right)=\log n^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\log n}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\log n}}\log n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{\log n}=\Theta(\sqrt{\log n})$$

Answer (score 1):

To prove $2^{\sqrt{2\log n}} \in O(\sqrt{2}^{\log n})$, you should note that $\sqrt{2}^{\log n} = \left(\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{\log n}}\right)^{\sqrt{\log n}}$.

To prove $2^{\sqrt{2\log n}} \in \Omega(\log^2n)$, you should note that $\log ^2n = 2^{2\log \log n}$.

It will simplify the comparisons you have to do.

Comment: I still cant get it. can you help more with the omega?

Comment: @violet, because $\sqrt{y}$ dominates $\log y$.

Comment: @zkutch I was thinking that taking exp of both sides of an inequality is not a valid step, but is the idea here that we can let c=1 and it is thereore a valid step!?

Comment: For base>1 exp is increasing function, so $x>y \Leftrightarrow 2^x>2^y$. And, because, root vanish logarithm, we can take any constant.

Comment: but in this case, what allows this method of proving to work is that we can let c=1 specifically. is this correct? because if we have cf(x)<g(x) and we do 2^cf(x)<2^g(x)- this may not be true in situations where c!=1? correct?

Comment: Power of $2$ is increasing means you can put any variables to definition, with $c=1$ or without it.